# Deciding which Java event pattern/model to use

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling

I have a non-gui application in the planning stage that will act as a controller for slave devices on a RS485 network.  Each slave device is addressable and can do rudimentary things like display text on a simple LCD screen and accept text from a keyboard and even different types of card reads.  The devices have a "don't speak unless spoken to" method of communicating, which means the controller is polling each device on the 'wire'.

So there is a single point of communication, a TCP socket to a RS485-to-Ethernet converter device.

I've written something similar in the past, but this was before event-driven anything and no threading either.  We're talking System V Unix here folks.  :-)

So, I have messed around with threading in Java and was scrounging around here doing some research.  Found out about the Observable class and Observer interface.  Looks OK to me, but why do I want to notify all of my Observers when they are addressable?  If I use a multithreaded approach I don't want to wake all of my threads with data that isn't applicable to them.

So my question is:  which is a better way to go here?  Observable/Observer is simple and can get me going right away, but it seems like a waste for all threads/Observers to have to wake up for messages that aren't for them, even if it is a simple matter of using an 'if' statement to test the incoming object against 'this'.  Is it better to implement the AWT ActionListener method or start with EventObject?  What else?

Comment: Sounds like you want a Publish/Subscribe pattern

Comment: Check out JMS, [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html), [HornetQ](http://hornetq.jboss.org/), [EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) by Google, [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/publish-subscribe-channel.html)

Comment: Check out project Reactor: https://github.com/reactor/reactor

Answer (score 0):

I think that the part of your application that receives client requests and decides which device to contact doesn't need multi-threading. You can use awt ActionListener, sure, but it's also easy enough to roll your own event loop.

As for the communication with devices themselves, if it is slow, it might be viable for it to happen in a separate thread (worker thread), so that it doesn't block the event loop. You would typically use an ExecutorService backed with a thread pool.

Sending response back would either send response data from the worker thread directly or it might go back to the event loop from where it would be sent back to the client.

Client can now be implemented as either synchronous, waiting idly for the response, or asynchronous, returning immediately, usually a Future object that can be polled later for the result.

Also check out the Disruptor pattern, it provides fast inter-thread messaging with very little overhead if used correctly.